# Is there evidence to suggest that Arne Darvin is from the House of Mokai?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, star-trek-discovery

In the Star Trek:[TOS Episode 44](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trouble_with_Tribbles) *The Trouble with Tribbles*, we meet [Arne Davin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arne_Darvin), a [Klingon Spy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_Intelligence), who has been surgically altered to look human.

In the Star Trek: Discovery Episode [S01E04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery#ep4) *The Butchers Knife Cares Not for the Lamb's Cry* we see [L'Rell](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/lrell) tell [Voq](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Voq) he must come back to the Matriarchs of her clan. We know that L'Rell is from the House of [Mokai](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/House_of_Mo%27Kai). In [S01E05](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery#ep5) *Choose Your Pain* We discover that L'Rell's language skills come from her house, which has an expertise in deception.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that Arne Darvin is from the House of Mokai?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The concept of Klingon Houses didn't appear until *The Next Generation*, and while Mo'Kai might have been noted for spying and deception, they certainly weren't the only ones doing so. The House of Duras certainly engaged in it as well during the TNG period.